# Find the sum of series: $\sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^k \binom{n}{k} \binom{2n-k}{n}$

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

To find the sum:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^k \binom{n}{k} \binom{2n-k}{n}$$

**Try**:

I do not have any clue about the question. I was thinking of finding coefficient of some required power in a binomial expansion, but wasn't able to proceed as the power of $x$ seems to be non-constant in each term ($x^{n+k}$).

Please give a small hint!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k = 0}^{n}\pars{-1}^{k}{n \choose k}{2n - k \choose n} & =
\sum_{k = 0}^{n}\pars{-1}^{k}{n \choose k}\bracks{z^{n}}\pars{1 + z}^{2n - k}
\\[5mm] & =
\bracks{z^{n}}\pars{1 + z}^{2n}
\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{n \choose k}\pars{-\,{1 \over 1 + z}}^{k}
\\[5mm] & =
\bracks{z^{n}}\pars{1 + z}^{2n}\pars{1 - {1 \over 1 + z}}^{n}
\\[5mm] & =
\bracks{z^{n}}\pars{1 + z}^{n}\,z^{n} = \bbx{\large 1} \\ &
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I think I need to practice more on algebraic manipulation.

Comment: That's a good idea. Thanks. $\left(\angle \quad \angle \atop {\Huge \smile}\right)$

Comment: Sorry for off-topic question - do you type out latex or use some software?

Comment: I type $\LaTeX$. The above icon is $\LaTeX$ too. It's the code: $\texttt{\$\left(\angle\quad\angle\atop{\Huge\smile}\right)\$}$

Answer (score 3):

Note that
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^k \binom{n}{k} \binom{2n-k}{n}&=\sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^k \binom{n}{k} \binom{2n-k}{n-k}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^k \binom{n}{k} (-1)^{n-k}\binom{-(n+1)}{n-k}\\
&=(-1)^{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} \binom{-(n+1)}{n-k}\\
&=(-1)^{n}\binom{n-(n+1)}{n}=1.
\end{align*}
where we used 
$$\binom{2n-k}{n-k}=\frac{(2n-k)\cdots(n+1)}{(n-k)!}=
(-1)^{n-k}\frac{(-n-1)\cdots(-2n+k)}{(n-k)!}=
(-1)^{n-k}\binom{-n-1}{n-k}$$

and the [Vandermonde's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity).

Comment: I am feeling so dumb right now! Thanks!

Comment: @Robert, could you explain how you went from expression after first '=' to the one after the second '='? Thanks

Comment: @sku Yes. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to exploit the [Melzak's identity](https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.07006): $$f\left(x+y\right)=x\dbinom{x+n}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\left(-1\right)^{k}\dbinom{n}{k}\frac{f\left(y-k\right)}{x+k},\, x,y\in\mathbb{R},\, x\neq-k $$ where $f $ is an algebraic polynomial up to degree $n $. So taking $f\left(z\right)=\dbinom{z+n}{n}z$ we get $$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\left(-1\right)^{k}\dbinom{n}{k}\dbinom{y+n-k}{n}\frac{y-k}{-x-k}=-\frac{\dbinom{n+y+x}{n}}{x\dbinom{x+n}{n}}\left(x+y\right)$$ so taking $y=n$ and the limit $x\rightarrow-n$ we get $$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\left(-1\right)^{k}\dbinom{n}{k}\dbinom{2n-k}{n}=-\lim_{x\rightarrow-n}\frac{\dbinom{2n+x}{n}}{x\dbinom{x+n}{n}}\left(n+x\right)=\color{red}{1}$$ as wanted.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the simpler  and shorter way would be:
$$
\eqalign{
  & \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,n} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,k} \left( \matrix{
  n \cr 
  k \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{
  2n - k \cr 
  n \cr}  \right)}  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,n} {\left( \matrix{
  k - n - 1 \cr 
  k \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{
  2n - k \cr 
  n \cr}  \right)}  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,n} {\left( \matrix{
  k - n - 1 \cr 
  k \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{
  2n - k \cr 
  n - k \cr}  \right)}  =   \cr 
  &  = \left( \matrix{
  n \cr 
  n \cr}  \right) = 1 \cr} 
$$
 where

- 1st step : *Upper Negation* $  \left({ - 1} \right)^{\,k} \left( \matrix{
    n \cr 
    k \cr}\right)=\left( \matrix{
    {k-n-1} \cr 
    k \cr}\right)$
- 2nd step: *Symmetry* $\left( \matrix{
    n \cr 
    k \cr}\right)=\left( \matrix{
    n \cr 
    {n-k} \cr}\right)\quad |0 \le \text{integer} \,n$
- 3rd step: *Double Convolution* 
  $$
  \sum\limits_{a\, \le \,k\, \le \,b} {\left( \matrix{
    k - c \cr 
    k - a \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{
    d - k \cr 
    b - k \cr}  \right)}  = \left( \matrix{
    d - c + 1 \cr 
    b - a \cr}  \right)
  $$

Answer (score 1):

There is also a combinatorial solution. Consider the following problem:

> How many subsets of $\{1,2,\dots,2n\}$ of size $n$ contain none of the numbers in $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$?

On the one hand, the answer is obviously $1$; the only such subset is $\{n+1,n+2,\dots, 2n\}$.

On the other hand, we can solve this with the principle of inclusion exclusion. Letting $E_i$ be the number of subsets of size $n$ which *do* contain $i$, we need to count $E_1^\complement\cap E_2^\complement\cap \dots \cap E_n^\complement$. For any $k$ indices $i_1,\dots,i_k$, the size of the intersection $E_{i_1}\cap E_{i_2}\cap \dots \cap E_{i_k}$ is $\binom{2n-k}n$. Taking the alternating sum over all such subsets of indices, we get your sum.

Answer (score 0):

This is inspired by the answer of @Marco Cantarini that noticed that the expression
$$k \mapsto \binom{2n-k}{n}= \colon P(k)$$
is a polynomial $P$ in $k$ of degree $n$ with leading coefficient $\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}$. The sum therefore equals $(-1)^n (\Delta^n P )(0) = (-1)^n \cdot n! \cdot \frac{(-1)^n}{n!}= 1$.

Details: we know that if $f(x)$ is a polynomial in $x$ of degree $n$ with leading term $a$ then $\Delta f(x) \colon =f(x+1) - f(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $n-1$ and leading term $n \cdot a$. We conclude that $\Delta^n f$ is a constant polynomial  $n! a$. Note that we have
$$\Delta^n f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^{n-k} \binom{n}{k} f(x+k)$$

Now take $x=0$ and the initial polynomial.